# Finding Pi variables from matrix. From PageRank Algorithm.

Tags: matrices

$$\pmatrix{\pi_1 & \pi_2 & \pi_3} = \pmatrix{\pi_1 & \pi_2 & \pi_3}\pmatrix{\frac{1}{6} & \frac{4}{6} & \frac{1}{6} \\ \frac{5}{12} & \frac{2}{12} & \frac{5}{12} \\ \frac{1}{6} & \frac{4}{6} & \frac{1}{6} \\}$$

Answer:  $$\pi_1=\frac{5}{18}$$ $$\pi_2=\frac{8}{18}$$ $$\pi_3=\frac{5}{18}$$

Could someone please explain how to find these variables.

Comment: Gaussian Elimination?

Comment: I don't know what the problem would be called. The teacher was teaching PageRank and this is a part he just assumed everyone knew. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The key terms are the [Perron-Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) and the *stable state* of a *Markov chain*. In practice, this vector $\pi$ is found as the eigenvector for the eigenvalue $1$, and is normalized so that the sum of its components is $1$.

Subtract $1$ along the diagonal to get 
$$B=\pmatrix{-\frac{5}{6} & \frac{4}{6} & \frac{1}{6} \\ \frac{5}{12} & -\frac{10}{12} & \frac{5}{12} \\ \frac{1}{6} & \frac{4}{6} & -\frac{5}{6} }$$
Since we multiply by the matrix on the right, the desired vector is in the kernel of $B^T$. The [Scilab](http://www.scilab.org/) command `v=kernel(B')'` outputs

```
v  =    0.4682929    0.7492686    0.4682929
```

This is normalized to have length $1$, but we want the sum of components to be $1$. The command `v/sum(v)` does the job:

```
0.2777778    0.4444444    0.2777778
```

which is your vector. Of course, with sufficient patience one can do it by hand as well.